# My Dropdown button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My dropdown button doesn't work anymore. I have a problem that the dropdown button only appears if I click on a certain part of the button. I tried to fix that, but now the dropdown doesn't work at all and I can't undo my changes. Can somebody help me out?

```js
/*funktion für dropdown button*/
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('inhalt').classList.toggle('show');
}
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdiv')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];    
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*Dropdown Icon*/
.dropdiv {
  background-color: #001155;
  width: 40px;
  height: 22px;
}
.dropdivs{
  height: 4px;width: 29px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  border: #001155;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbutton {
  background-color: #001155;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*dropdown*/
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/*dropdown Inhalt*/
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  right:0;
}
/* Dropdown Links*/
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}    
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">
    <div class="dropdiv">
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div id="inhalt" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.google.ch/">Google</a>
    <a href="https://intranet.swisscom.com/home/#/">Intranet</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div> 
<p class="title">CRUD APP</p>
```

Comment: You have added jQuery as a tag but don't use it in your markup. For example, `document.getElementById('inhalt').classList.toggle('show');` could become `$('#inhalt').toggleClass("show");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".dropdown").on("click",function(){

         $(".dropdown-content").toggle(500);

     })

 })
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            
            .dropdiv {
    background-color: #001155;
    width: 40px;
    height: 22px;
}

.dropdivs{
    height: 4px;
    width: 29px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    border: #001155;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbutton {
    background-color: #001155;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/*dropdown*/
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/*dropdown Inhalt*/
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right:0;
}

/* Dropdown Links*/
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
            .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
           
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbutton">
          <div class="dropdiv">
            <div class="dropdivs"></div>
            <div class="dropdivs"></div>
            <div class="dropdivs"></div>
        </div>
        </button>
          <div id="inhalt" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="https://www.google.ch/">Google</a>
            <a href="https://intranet.swisscom.com/home/#/">Intranet</a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
          </div>
      </div> 
<p class="title">CRUD APP</p> 

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     
     $(".dropdown").on("click",function(){
         
         $(".dropdown-content").toggle(500);
              
     })
     
 })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using jquery but pure javascript this is the fixed code!

```js
/*funktion für dropdown button*/
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('inhalt').classList.toggle('show');
}


    document.querySelector('.dropbutton').onclick = function (event) {

            var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            alert();
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }else{
                openDropdown.classList.add('show');
                }
            }
    }
```

```css
/*Dropdown Icon*/

.dropdiv {
    background-color: #001155;
    width: 40px;
    height: 22px;
}

.dropdivs{
    height: 4px;
    width: 29px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    border: #001155;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbutton {
    background-color: #001155;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/*dropdown*/
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/*dropdown Inhalt*/
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right:0;
}

/* Dropdown Links*/
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">
  <div class="dropdiv">
    <div class="dropdivs"></div>
    <div class="dropdivs"></div>
    <div class="dropdivs"></div>
</div>
</button>
  <div id="inhalt" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.google.ch/">Google</a>
    <a href="https://intranet.swisscom.com/home/#/">Intranet</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div> 
<p class="title">CRUD APP</p>
```